# interview questions: find all numbers that contain k 1's

Tags: binary, combinations

I was asked to implement the following function:

```
void printNumber(int N, int K);
```

It prints all binary numbers of length `N`, which contains `K` ones.

e.g.

```
input: printNumber(3,2) 
output: 
011
101
110
```

I tried to solve this problem by manipulating the binary as string and used recursion, but I guess there are some bit operation trick that could solve this problem in a nicer way.

Any bit-magic I can apply here?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/630384

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate all binary strings of length n with k bits set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851134/generate-all-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-k-bits-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to generate them

```
   def go(n,k):
       if n == 0:
           if k > 0:
               return []
           if k == 0:
               return ['']

       return ['0'+x for x in go(n-1,k)] + ['1'+x for x in go(n-1,k-1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the binary value by using Integer.toBinaryString(i) and then take out the permutation of that value