# Generate only those binary strings of length n with maximum k consecutive zeros

Tags: algorithm, binary, nlp, bit, bitmask

What is the most efficient way to generate only those binary strings of length n, which have a maximum of k consecutive zeroes.

For eg :- if n = 3, k = 2:

0 0 1

0 1 0

0 1 1

1 0 0

1 0 1

1 1 0

1 1 1

and not 000

Note : I need this method for my research (NLP), where I am using bit strings to generate sentences with all possible n-grams.
I have tried enumerating all the binary strings, however, since the number of binary strings is exponential in the length of the sentence 2^(n-1), the code is crashing if n > 30. Hence, I am limited to only generating those bit-strings with the above condition for computational feasibility.

Comment: how about a loop from `0` to `k` using this algorithm? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851134/generate-all-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-k-bits-set?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple recursive version (Delphi)

```
  procedure Generate(ZeroCount, MaxZeroCount, Len, MaxLen: Integer; s: string);
  begin
    if Len = MaxLen then
      Output(s)
    else begin
      if ZeroCount < MaxZeroCount then
        Generate(ZeroCount + 1, MaxZeroCount, Len + 1, MaxLen, s + '0');
      Generate(0, MaxZeroCount, Len + 1, MaxLen, s + '1');
    end;
  end;
```

variant for integer value instead of string

```
  if ZeroCount < MaxZeroCount then
    Generate(ZeroCount + 1, MaxZeroCount, Len + 1, MaxLen, Value shl 1);
  Generate(0, MaxZeroCount, Len + 1, MaxLen, (Value shl 1) or 1);
```

output for Generate(0, 2, 0, 5, '');

```
00100
00101
00110
00111
01001
01010
01011
01100
01101
01110
01111
10010
10011
10100
10101
10110
10111
11001
11010
11011
11100
11101
11110
11111
```

Comment: Thanks @MBo! You are (almost) perfectly right! However, the above code does not yet generate certain strings such as - 00100, 00101 etc. Hence, resetting ZeroCount to 0 in Generate(0, MaxZeroCount, Len + 1, MaxLen, s + '1') helps generate the comprehensive list. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, it's my fault. Fixed.