# Generating an array of partially random boolean values based on certain criteria

Tags: arrays, random, language-agnostic

I am trying to generate random data based on some criteria. I am stuck on how to start so I don't have any code.

I just want some guide on how I can achieve that. You need not provide complete code.

So, coming to the problem, lets say we have this existing data:

```
Total - 10
Won   -  7
Lost  -  3
Longest Winning Streak - 5
Longest Losing Streak - 2
```

Now I need to generate an array of random boolean values (`true` representing a win and `false` representing a loss) which fulfills the above criteria.

So, in this case the output can be any of the following:

```
0011011111
1111101100
1010011111
..........
```

Its the streak part that bothers me. If it weren't for the streak, I could have generated seven `1(s)` and three `0(s)` and then randomly shuffled them.

**Note:** I would prefer solutions in C#, VB.NET, JavaScript, or Python but any language is welcome.

Comment: 1. What have you tried already? 2. Any language is welcome? Bad idea, since we only solve [*special issues*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if your question accept all the languages, then there's no *a correct answer*.

Comment: one approach would be to create all the combinations of wins and loses then filter out the ones that don't match the streak criteria.

Comment: Should I then post this at Code Golf?

Comment: @KevinGuan If you would bother reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you would see that this question isn't off-topic. And also asking about common programming problems/algorithms is allowed afaik

Comment: @KevinGuan I could certainly have made this C# only but since it is related with the fundamental data types and the .NET framework doesn't come to play, I thought it would be better to not make this language specific as it would provide a wider scope of being answered.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ: So the problem is, if I posted an answer which is in Python, another one posted one in C# and they're both correct. Which one is the *correct answer* and you would accept? I didn't say your question is off-topic BTW, I meant **too broad**.

Comment: Then I would request any answerer to post pseudo-code :)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Do as you please as long as there's some explanation. I don't even need code. Just provide an algorithm. I don't want 12 bytes of Pyth not understanding what is going on :)

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ: Err...a pseudo-code answer isn't a really answer since the code *doesn't work*.

Comment: Someone create a chatroom please.

Comment: create the win streak and the losing streak.  Copy the win to a random start location, then the loosing; then fill in the blanks.  The trick will be working out the range so that the longer streak leaves room for the shorter

Comment: @Plutonix hmm. Good... better than criticizing my question. Any idea how I would fill in the gaps?

Comment: Thats not the hard part - start with an int array of 1s,  the wins would reset to -1, losses to 0, the ones to fill in would be 1 - change them using Random.NextBoolean. then convert the array to a boolean array (off the top of my head)

Comment: @Plutonix aha got it.. I'm kind of late in understanding things but thanks for help. 'working out the range so that the longer streak leaves room' - That's easy enough it seems. I'll now try and implement it in my program.

Comment: You dont really need a Win and Lose array, just a way to tell Wins(-1) from Losses(0) and unset(1).  The win start index > 0 and < 10-win length, but may need to repick until there is room for (Loss Length) consecutive values

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ  If you change title and demand in python then i can post answer..

Comment: Post it. The **first** correct answer will be accepted. Other languages will be upvoted as well if they are correct and posted within the next two days only.

Comment: @SIslam it already has a python tag

Comment: something else to watch for is once you set the Wins, then the Losses, setting the Leftovers to NextBoolean could accidentally extend either of the streaks

Comment: That is the problem I faced as well after trying your solution.

Comment: just dont use Random.NextBoolean for leftovers - set it to the opposite of the value at the next index...unless it is the last index, then use the preceeding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest a genetic algorithm.

```
    class Program
{
    static int len = 10;
    static int win = 7;
    static int lws = 5;
    static int lls = 2;

    static Random rnd = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int genSz = 15;
        var generation = new List<Chromosome>();
        Helper.Repeat(() => generation.Add(new Chromosome()), genSz);

        int gen = 1;
        while (generation.First().Fitness != 0)
        {
            //procreation
            Helper.Repeat(() => {
                int x1 = rnd.Next(genSz / 2);
                int x2 = rnd.Next(genSz);
                generation.Add(new Chromosome(generation[x1], generation[x2]));
            }, genSz);
            //selection
            generation = generation.OrderBy(x => x.Fitness).Take(genSz).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("GENERATION " + gen++);
            foreach (var x in generation)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class Chromosome
    {
        bool[] genes = new bool[len];

        public Chromosome() { }

        public Chromosome(Chromosome p1, Chromosome p2)
        {
            //crossingover
            rnd.Shuffle(ref p1, ref p2);    //may reorder parents or not
            var x = rnd.Next(len);
            Array.Copy(p1.genes, 0, genes, 0, x);
            Array.Copy(p2.genes, x, genes, x, len - x);
            //mutation
            if (rnd.Flip())
            {
                x = rnd.Next(len);
                genes[x] = !genes[x];
            }
        }
        public int Fitness
        {
            get
            {
                int w = genes.Count(g => g);
                int l = len - w;
                int ws = genes.LongestStreak(g => g);
                int ls = genes.LongestStreak(g => !g);
                return Math.Abs(w - win) + Math.Abs(lws - ws) + Math.Abs(lls - ls);
            }
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "[" + new string(genes.Select(g => g ? '*' : '.').ToArray()) + "] " + Fitness.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public static class Helper
{
    public static bool Flip(this Random rnd) => rnd.Next(2) == 0;
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this Random rnd, ref T a, ref T b, bool allowNoChange = true)
    {
        if (allowNoChange && rnd.Flip()) return; //no reordering
        T tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp;
    }

    public static int LongestStreak<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Predicate<T> selector)
    {
        int current = 0;
        int longest = 0;
        foreach (T x in sequence)
        {
            if (selector(x))
            {
                current++;
                if (current > longest) longest = current;
            }
            else
            {
                current = 0;
            }
        }
        return longest;
    }

    public static void Repeat(this Action action, int N)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) action();
    }
}
```

[image]

Second variant - brute force. Can be used if the sequence is short. Also you can get all possible variants with it.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var res = new[] { true, false }.Words(10).Where(w => {
            return
                w.Count(g => g) == 7 &&
                w.LongestStreak(g => g) == 5 &&
                w.LongestStreak(g => !g) == 2;
        });
        foreach (var v in res)
        {
            foreach (var b in v)
            {
                Console.Write(b ? "*" : ".");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(res.Count());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class Helper
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Words<T>(this IEnumerable<T> alphabet, int len)
    {
        foreach (var l in alphabet)
        {
            if (len == 1)
            {
                yield return l.Yield();
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var w in alphabet.Words(len - 1))
                {
                    yield return w.Prepend(l);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T item)
    {
        yield return item;
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rest, T first)
    {
        yield return first;
        foreach (var item in rest)
            yield return item;
    }

    public static int LongestStreak<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Predicate<T> selector)
    {
        int current = 0;
        int longest = 0;
        foreach (T x in sequence)
        {
            if (selector(x))
            {
                current++;
                if (current > longest) longest = current;
            }
            else
            {
                current = 0;
            }
        }
        return longest;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This does a good job but can you test it for `111,60,10,4` and give screenshot of output? At present python isn't even starting on my system.

Comment: @Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ, second variant is no go with such conditions but genetic alg has found a solution pretty fast: https://i.gyazo.com/976fda59612a39509b0ddda408e1e4c6.png

Comment: Great. Accepting this answer.

Comment: ok now i'm on my pc but this doesn't work. Oh no it seems I didn't press the keys after each generation. wait I'll test it one last time.

Comment: you may also have taken a bad version where number of loses was considered what is bad. ensure there's no lst variable.

Comment: Sorry this works perfectly even with 110 60 10 4 and in every situation. Thanks a lot. You are a genius

Comment: all credits to darwin/biology ;-)

Comment: Charles Robert Darwin, in fact.

Comment: ps: actually sometimes it does stuck, so just restart it after say 1000 generations

Comment: Yes discovered that too. But it doesn't matter as long as it works (which it does).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use an algorithm to select `k` bits (your `won` number) from a length-`n` (your `total` number) string. Here, I use the [`kbits(n, k)` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851134/generate-all-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-k-bits-set) written by @foglebird. You can then filter out the undesired permutations using a list comprehension.

```
import itertools

def kbits(n, k):
    result = []
    for bits in itertools.combinations(range(n), k):
        s = ['0'] * n
        for bit in bits:
            s[bit] = '1'
        result.append(''.join(s))
    return result

total = 10
won = 7
lost = 3
max_win = 5
max_lose = 2

answer = [x for x in kbits(total, won) if '1'*(max_win+1) not in x and '0'*(max_lose+1) not in x]
```

Comment: Testing it [here](http://pythonfiddle.com/), I find that it outputs an array of array of boolean. How do I filter out the correct ones?

Answer (score 1):

I had an answer posted, then noticed I was missed some key requirements.  I added and changed some stuff to address those missing elements.

The core method fails most of the time, but it does so quickly enough that you can do it in a loop until you get a good answer.  Depending on the actual values, in cases where there are very few legal results, it seems like you need to luck out.

The steps used:

- Pick a random spot for the longest streak (Win in the example)
- Bracket the streak with losses to prevent extending it when setting leftovers
- Find the indices with enough consecutive slots to hold the loss streak
- Pick a random one and set the loss streak (returns if there are none)
- Set all the Leftovers as `Not the value at n-1` to avoid extending or creating a new streak

So, it becomes hit or miss whether then WinCount and LossCount are correct.  That seems easier to stumble upon than streaks of the right size.  A wrapper method tests the result to reject and rerun.  With the given values, it usually find a winner in the first 10 or so times.

---

The core method to construct a string representation, and a helper:

```vb
' ToDo change to return Bool() = string is easier to read
Private Function FarhamStreaks(winStrk As Int32, loseStrk As Int32, total As Int32) As String

    ' -1 == not set
    Dim result = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, total).ToArray

    ' set longest streak first
    Dim wNDX = RNG.Next(0, total + 1 - winStrk)
    For n As Int32 = 0 To winStrk - 1
        result(wNDX + n) = 1
    Next
    ' bracket with losers so the w streak cant extend
    If wNDX > 0 Then result(wNDX - 1) = 0
    If wNDX + winStrk < result.Length - 1 Then result(wNDX + winStrk) = 0

    ' look for eligible consecutive starting slots
    ' might be none
    Dim lossNdx As New List(Of Int32)
    For n As Int32 = 0 To result.Count - 1
        Dim count = CountConsecutiveLooserSlotsFrom(n, result)

        If (n + 1) < result.Count AndAlso count >= loseStrk Then
            lossNdx.Add(n)
        End If
    Next

    If lossNdx.Count = 0 Then
        ' do over 
        ' the code has never gotten here
        ' but depends on the mix of values
        Return ""
    End If

    ' set losses
    Dim lNdx = lossNdx(RNG.Next(0, lossNdx.Count))
    For n As Int32 = 0 To loseStrk - 1
        result(lNdx + n) = 0
    Next

    ' set the leftovers based on next value to avoid 
    ' extending streaks
    For n As Int32 = 0 To result.Length - 1
        If result(n) = -1 Then
            If n > 0 Then
                result(n) = If(result(n - 1) = 0, 1, 0)
            Else
                result(n) = If(result(n + 1) = 0, 1, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Dim resultString = String.Join(",", result)

    ' convert to boolean
    Dim realResult(total) As Boolean
    For n As Int32 = 0 To total - 1
        realResult(n) = Convert.ToBoolean(result(n))
    Next

    Return resultString
End Function

' find candidate slots for the shorter streak:
Private Function CountConsecutiveLooserSlotsFrom(ndx As Integer, theArray As Int32()) As Int32
    Dim count As Int32 = 1    ' including ndx

    For n As Int32 = ndx To theArray.Length - 2
        If theArray(n) <> 1 AndAlso theArray(n + 1) <> 1 Then
            count += 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return count
End Function
```

The method to validate a result candidate (and performance metrics):

```
Private Function MakeFarhamStreak(wins As Int32, winStreak As Int32,
                                  lossStreak As Int32,
                                  total As Int32) As String
    Const MaxTries As Int32 = 999
    Dim losses = (total - wins)
    Dim reverse As Boolean = (lossStreak > winStreak)
    Dim candidate As String
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    Dim pass, fail As Int32
    Dim count As Int32

    sw.Start()

    For n As Int32 = 0 To MaxTries

        If reverse Then
            candidate = FarhamStreaks(lossStreak, winStreak, total)
            ' to do: un-reverse (Not) the results - 
        Else
            candidate = FarhamStreaks(winStreak, lossStreak, total)
        End If

        Dim result = candidate.Split(","c)

        ' test win count
        count = candidate.Where(Function(f) f = "1").Count
        If count <> wins Then
            fail += 1
            Continue For
        End If

        ' test loss count
        count = candidate.Where(Function(f) f = "0").Count
        If count <> losses Then
            fail += 1
            Continue For
        End If

        Dim tmp = candidate.Replace(","c, "")

        ' test win streak size
        Dim wstreaks = tmp.Select(Function(c, i) tmp.Substring(i).
                                      TakeWhile(Function(q) q = c AndAlso q = "1").
                                      Count()).
                                  Max
        If wstreaks <> winStreak Then
            fail += 1
            Continue For
        End If

        Dim lstreaks = tmp.Select(Function(c, i) tmp.Substring(i).
                          TakeWhile(Function(q) q = c AndAlso q = "0").
                          Count()).
                      Max
        If lstreaks <> lossStreak Then
            fail += 1
            Continue For
        End If

        pass += 1
        If pass = 1 Then
            Console.WriteLine("First Pass in {0}ms  (try # {1} = {2})",
                              sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, n, candidate)
            ' normally, return at this point
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

It is easier to fit the shorter streak around the longer one, so it reverses the parm order as needed.  There isnt code to flip/Not the results.

results:

> First Pass in 18ms  (try # 4 = 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)
>   Total FAILURES 753   75.38%
>   Total     Pass 247   24.72%
>   Total time for 999 candidates  29ms

It found the first passing value on try #4 - with the 10, 7w, 5ws, 2ls values it usually finds one in the first 10.