# function returning k-digit numbers from an arrays of n digits

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want to construct a function `showNum(ar,k)` getting all the k-digit numbers from array `ar`.

For example, `showNum([1,2,3],2)` should return `12,13,21,23,31,32`

and`showNum([1,2,3],1)` should return `1,2,3`.

My code works well with the case that `k` is fix.

For instance, the case `k` is 3.

My idea is to loop 3 times.

```
   function showNum(a){
   var ar = [];
   var n = a.length;
   for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
       for(j = 0; j <= n; j++){
           for(k = 0; k <= n; k++){
           if(a[i] != a[j] && a[i] != a[k] && a[k] != a[j]) ar.push(a[i]*100 + a[j]*10 + a[k]);
           }
       }
   }
   return ar;
}
```

But when `k` is arbitrarily less than `n`, I don't know how to loop.

Comment: In this case, you'll want to try to research generating binary range algorithm
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851134/generate-all-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-k-bits-set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is really helpful here: Inside of the loop, make a recursive call to iterate the numbers again. This can be done easily using a generator:

```
 function* combinations(values, depth, previous = []) {
   if(depth <=0) {
     yield previous.reduce((res, n, i) => res + n * 10 ** i, 0);
     return;
  }

  for(const value of values) {
    if(previous.includes(value))
        continue;
    yield* combinations(values, depth - 1, [...previous, value]);
  }
}
```

Usable as:

```
 [...combinations([1, 2, 3], 2)]
```

```js
function* combinations(values, depth, previous = []) {
  if(depth <=0) {
     yield previous.reduce((res, n, i) => res + n * 10 ** i, 0);
     return;
  }

  for(const value of values) {
    if(previous.includes(value))
        continue;
    yield* combinations(values, depth - 1, [...previous, value]);
  }
}

console.log([...combinations([1, 2, 3], 2)])
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Btw, the generator function seems unfamiliar with me since I am a complete beginer.