# How to generate all possible n-bits binary numbers?

Tags: c#, binary, numbers, combinations, bit

How can I generate all possible binary numbers like below:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111


List<int> GetAllPossibleBinaryNumbers(int length) {
}
```

In above `GetAllPossibleBinaryNumbers` accepts `length` as the number of bits, and returns all possible binary values.

Comment: I mean look through all possible binary numbers

Comment: @user960567 Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Yes I wanna all possible binary numbers of length n

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate all binary strings of length n with k bits set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851134/generate-all-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-k-bits-set)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-the-binary-strings-of-n-bits/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user wants to count, but has shown no effort.

Comment: The duplicate you cited generates values with _k_ bits set, not _all_ possible combinations. In any event, the [Help Vampire](https://web.archive.org/web/20180216144029/https://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm) has posted a problem statement that shows _zero_ bits set for effort. They couldn't even be bothered to suggest that the values shown were for `length = 4`.

Comment: @OlivierRogier There is only _one_ value for `k = length`: all bits set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate how many numbers there are (which is 2^n), start a loop at 0 and end at 2^n - 1.

```
int length = 4;
int numbers = 1 << length; // equivalent of 2^n
for(int i=0; i<numbers; i++)
{
    string binary = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
    string leading_zeroes = "00000000".Substring(0,length-binary.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(leading_zeroes + binary);
}
```

Comment: I wanna list down all numbers

Comment: Your idea worked. Thanks a lot. `for (int i = (int)Math.Pow(2, size-1); i < (int)Math.Pow(2, size); i++ ){
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i, 2));
                }`

Comment: @user960567: that code does not start at 0.