# Bitwise shift to generate all possible permutations in C

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation, permutation, combinations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating multiple numbers with certain number of bits set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506807/creating-multiple-numbers-with-certain-number-of-bits-set)

I'm attempting to write some code which will put each possible combination of numbers in an array by shifting the bits across.

For example, I wanted to find all possible combinations of 3 bits (where the max a digit can be is 6) the array should contain:

```
000111
001011
001101
001110
010011
010101
010110
011001
011010
011100
100011
```

And so on...

From what I've interpreted, when the last position bit is 1 we shift the number by 1 (x >> 1) and add a 1 at the start. However, I'm unsure how to code the rest. I'm using C to write this.

Also - as far as I can tell this is a colex sequence, however, I'm all ears if there is another sequence that will give me the same end result (array with all possible combinations of k-bits with a constraint of N).

Comment: Dup of [Creating multiple numbers with certain number of bits set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506807/creating-multiple-numbers-with-certain-number-of-bits-set), [Generate all binary strings of length n with k bits set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851134/generate-all-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-k-bits-set).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this by generating the sequences recursively.

Let us define a recursive function `f(int index, int bits, int number)` that will take in the current `index` of the bit and the number of `bits` left to place, and the `number` generated so far. Then, you have the option of setting the current bit to 1 or to 0, and recursing from there.

Overall, the time complexity should be O(number of sequences), or O(N choose B), where N is the number of digits and B is the number of bits set to 1.

The function goes something like this:

```
void f(int index, int bits, int number) {
    if (index == 0) {
        if (bits == 0) {   // all required bits have been used
            emit_answer(number); // chuck number into an array, print it, whatever.
        }   
        return;
    }   

    if (index-1 >= bits) {  // If we can afford to put a 0 here
        f(index-1, bits, number);
    }   

    if (bits > 0) {  // If we have any 1s left to place
        f(index-1, bits-1, number | (1 << (index-1)));
    }   
}

// to call:
f(6, 3, 0);
```

For `N,B = 6,3` the output matches yours, and is in sorted order. Link to working example: http://codepad.org/qgd689ZM

Comment: Thanks @evgeny. Played around with this and learnt a few things. Just regarding the dupe - for those that are interested, follow the dupe link and read the Stanford resource. Helped me greatly.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a more efficient way, but you could just loop through the numbers and reject numbers that don't have a bit count of 3?  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer) for bit counting.

Comment: Then you have to go through 2^N combinations which can get pretty slow. Then again, he only needs it for 6 bits so it should be fine.

Comment: This is pretty slow, O(2^N) like quasiverse pointed out. My solution should generate all valid sequences without any waste.

Comment: OK, sure.  It's O(2^6).  Though, I'd argue that if speed is really an issue he could calculate the numbers ahead of time and save them.  Then it would be O(1) :-p  Not to mention the readability of this solution vs some of the others. *shrug*

Answer (score 2):

No need for any fancy recursion.  Some simple math will suffice (a division by a value which will always be a power of two is required).

```
    Function nextBits(ByVal prevVal As Integer)
        Dim lsOne As Integer = ((prevVal - 1) And Not prevVal) + 1
        Dim nextZero As Integer = (prevVal + lsOne) And Not prevVal
        Dim lowBits As Integer = ((nextZero \ lsOne \ 2) - 1)
        Return prevVal + lsOne + lowBits
    End Function
```

Nice and easy.

Comment: Uhh... my brain is hurting from the code. Also, what's the \ operator? And perhaps an explanation of why this works would help.

Comment: Please add more explanation to the code. OP seems to be interested in C code and this rather seems like VB-ish.

Comment: Sorry.  I tested the algorithm in VB.NET and copy/pasted the code.  The same algorithm should be readily adaptable to any other common language.  An aspect of VB.NET I forgot that people wouldn't know is that it uses a different operator for fractional division and whole-number division, so `15 / 4` yields 3.75, but `15 \ 4` yields 3.  The Python equivalent would be the `//` operator, and the C equivalent is the `/` operator with integer operands (necessitating an explicit cast or coercion if one wants to divide two integers to get a fractional result).

Comment: @Hritik: I thought the question had seemed like it might be homework-ish, so I figured I wanted to steer the person in the right direction without giving a solution they could use without thinking or understanding.  Trying some different values and seeing what each variable ends up being in binary should reveal what's going on.