# Haskell: Parallel code is slower than sequential version

Tags: multithreading, haskell, parallel-processing

I am pretty new to Haskell threads (and parallel programming in general) and I am not sure why my parallel version of an algorithm runs slower than the corresponding sequential version.

The algorithm tries to find all k-combinations without using recursion. For this, I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506807/creating-multiple-numbers-with-certain-number-of-bits-set?lq=1) helper function, which given a number with k bits set, returns the next number with the same number of bits set:

```
import Data.Bits    

nextKBitNumber :: Integer -> Integer
nextKBitNumber n
  | n == 0      = 0
  | otherwise   = ripple .|. ones
                       where smallest     = n .&. (-n)
                             ripple       = n + smallest
                             newSmallest  = ripple .&. (-ripple)
                             ones         = (newSmallest `div` smallest) `shiftR` 1 - 1
```

It is now easy to obtain sequentially all k-combinations in the range [(2^k - 1), (2^(n-k)+...+ 2^(n-1)):

```
import qualified Data.Stream as ST

combs :: Int -> Int -> [Integer]
combs n k = ST.takeWhile (<= end) $ kBitNumbers start
  where start = 2^k - 1
        end   = sum $ fmap (2^) [n-k..n-1]

kBitNumbers :: Integer -> ST.Stream Integer
kBitNumbers = ST.iterate nextKBitNumber

main :: IO ()
main = do
  params <- getArgs
  let n = read $ params !! 0
      k = read $ params !! 1
  print $ length (combs n k)
```

My idea is that this should be easily parallelizable splitting this range into smaller parts. For example:

```
start :: Int -> Integer
start k = 2 ^ k - 1

end :: Int -> Int -> Integer
end n k = sum $ fmap (2 ^) [n-k..n-1]

splits :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [(Integer, Integer, Int)]
splits n k numSplits = fixedRanges ranges []
  where s                       = start k
        e                       = end n k
        step                    = (e-s) `div` (min (e-s) (toInteger numSplits))
        initSplits              = [s,s+step..e]
        ranges                  = zip initSplits (tail initSplits)
        fixedRanges [] acc      = acc
        fixedRanges [x] acc     = acc ++ [(fst x, e, k)]
        fixedRanges (x:xs) acc  = fixedRanges xs (acc ++ [(fst x, snd x, k)])
```

At this point, I would like to run each split in parallel, something like:

```
runSplit :: (Integer, Integer, Int) -> [Integer]
runSplit (start, end, k) = ST.takeWhile (<= end) $ kBitNumbers (fixStart start)
  where fixStart s
                   | popCount s == k = s
                   | otherwise       = fixStart $ s + 1
```

For pallalelization I am using the `monad-par` package:

```
import Control.Monad.Par
import System.Environment
import qualified Data.Set as S

main :: IO ()
main = do
  params <- getArgs
  let n               = read $ params !! 0
      k               = read $ params !! 1
      numTasks        = read $ params !! 2
      batches         = runPar $ parMap runSplit (splits n k numTasks)
      reducedNumbers  = foldl S.union S.empty $ fmap S.fromList batches
  print $ S.size reducedNumbers
```

The result is that the sequential version is way faster and it uses little memory, while the parallel version consumes a lot of memory and it is noticeable slower.

What might be the reasons causing this? Are threads a good approach for this problem? For example, every thread generates a (potentially large) list of integers and the main thread reduces the results; are threads expected to need much memory or are simply meant to produce simple results (i.e. only cpu-intensive computations)?

I compile my program with `stack build --ghc-options -threaded --ghc-options -rtsopts  --executable-profiling --library-profiling` and run it with `./.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-6.1/7.10.3/bin/combinatorics 20 3 4 +RTS -pa -N4 -RTS` for n=20, k=3 and numSplits=4. An example of the profiling report for the parallel version can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jarandaf/597bdbd3aa2023dc4e3f96b1524de0ec) and for the sequential version [here](https://gist.github.com/jarandaf/56a8685a2d156537b20d1daf628f973b).

Comment: How are you running and testing the program?

Comment: Did you forget a parameter `k` on the `combs` function?

Comment: @pdexter have just updated my question with build/run commands and profiling reports for both parallel and sequential versions

Comment: What's your `main` for the sequential version? Thanks.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 tried to use threadscope with stack without much success (-eventlog flag seems not supported)

Comment: "not supported" - oh. then this should be reported to `stack` developers.

Comment: For further reference, -eventlog flag is indeed supported, just needed to drop --executable-profiling/--library-profiling options. Now I can use ThreadScope, yay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sequential version calling `combs` does not build up a list in memory since after `length` consumes an element it isn't needed anymore and is freed. Indeed, GHC may not even allocate storage for it.

For instance, this will take a while but won't consume a lot of memory:

```
main = print $ length [1..1000000000]  -- 1 billion
```

In your parallel version you are generating sub-lists, concatenating them together, building Sets, etc. and therefore the results of each sub-task have to be kept in memory.

A fairer comparison would be to have each parallel task compute the `length` of the k-bit numbers in its assigned range, and then add up the results. That way the k-bit numbers found by each parallel task wouldn't have to be kept in memory and would operate more like the sequential version.

**Update**

Here is an example of how to use `parMap`. <strike>Note: under 7.10.2 I've had mixed success getting the parallelism to fire - sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't.</strike> (Figured it out - I was using `-RTS -N2` instead of `+RTS -N2`.)

```
{-
compile with: ghc -O2 -threaded -rtsopts foo.hs

compare:

  time ./foo 26 +RTS -N1
  time ./foo 26 +RTS -N2
-}

import Data.Bits    
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import System.Environment

nextKBitNumber :: Integer -> Integer
nextKBitNumber n
  | n == 0      = 0
  | otherwise   = ripple .|. ones
                       where smallest     = n .&. (-n)
                             ripple       = n + smallest
                             newSmallest  = ripple .&. (-ripple)
                             ones         = (newSmallest `div` smallest) `shiftR` 1 - 1

combs :: Int -> Int -> [Integer]
combs n k = takeWhile (<= end) $ iterate nextKBitNumber start
  where start = 2^k - 1
        end   = shift start (n-k)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ( arg1 : _) <- getArgs
  let n = read arg1
  print $ parMap rseq (length . combs n) [1..n]
```

Comment: I understand your point and seems indeed logical, thank you. If you had to to explicitly obtain all numbers (not just the total number of k-combinations), how would you approach this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "obtain all numbers"?

Answer (score 0):

> good approaches for this problem

What do you mean by *this problem*? If it's how to write, analyze and tune a parallel Haskell program, then this is required background reading:

Simon Marlow: Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell
http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/pcph/

in particular, Section 15 (Debugging, Tuning, ..)

Use threadscope! (a graphical viewer for thread profile information generated by the Glasgow Haskell compiler) https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threadscope

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation! Actually, I ordered it some days ago and have just received it :) Some homework for the weekend...